# What is the use of `$.support.ownLast`?

Tags: jquery, jquery.support

I have been using `$.support` and what is the use of `ownLast` property of this. I searched google and comes with nothing. Could anyone please explain the usage of this?

Answer (score 1):

From the sources...

> ```
>     // Support: IE<9  
>     // Handle iteration over inherited properties before own properties.  
>     if ( jQuery.support.ownLast ) {
> ```